# Print periodic progress messages on the same line

Tags: bash

I have below command

```
command | sed 's/^/Progress: /g'
```

Output:

```
Progress: 1%
Progress: 2%
Progress: 3%
...
...
Progress: 100%
```

How can I limit that output to single line such that:

```
Progress: n%
```

Output should display only one line  Progress: n% and n keeps progressively changes

Comment: With an `echo` you can use the `-e` flag ..  `echo -e "\rProgress: $percent%"`

Comment: are you saying that you want *every* `Progress: ...` line to display on the terminal, but each successive line overwrites the previous line, so it looks like you have a single `Progress:` followed by a dynamically changing percentage?

Comment: You can use the `tr` command to translate newline to carriage return.

Comment: @markp-fuso yes

Comment: has to process the output of command to extract percentage and then display progressively

Comment: Tried tr with while read but it will replace last  100% line with : 99%. But it should be Progress: 100%

Comment: @HaruSuzuki Try: `command | sed -ue 's/.*/Progress: &%\r/' | stdbuf -o0 tr -d \\n`

Comment: why it was closed. I dont want to CREATE  progress bar. my progress is comming from output of command just had to display it progressively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
command|awk '{ printf "Progress: %s%%  \r", $1}'
```

This one is with ProgressBar

```
command|awk '{printf "\rProgress: " $1 "%% ["; for(c=0;c<$1;c++) printf "#"; printf "]" }'

Progress: 60% [############################################################]
```

Comment: awk is not tagges. command | sed | display. thats the way i wanted

Answer (score 1):

Use `\r` to go to the beginning of the line without going to the next line.

```
command | while read -r percent; do
    printf 'Progress: %d%%  \r' "$percent"
done
printf '\n'
```

Comment: I don't understand that, I think you have a typo.